# Add a new column in parquet and import into HBase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

Should I do something special to notify HBase that a new column has been added to the parquet (schema changed)?

Or it's like MongoDB that I can directly insert the new parquet in HBase (using BufferedMutator)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are writing to the existing column family then **`No need to notify HBase`**, As HBase **`dynamically stores all`** columns into defined column family (we just need to define column family and no need to define any column qualifier to Column families).

Just write the `parquet data to HBase` then HBase table will have the new column added for the specific **`rowkey`**.

Comment: Hi, I figured out the problem is when I write the dataframe to parquet with this new column in schema. It says "could not merge metadata", but I already specified .option("mergeSchema", "true"), do you know why ? Thanks